# Can't figure out this memory bug (crash after program finishes)

Tags: c++

Entire program: http://pastebin.com/x7gfSY5v

I made a parser that takes lines from a .txt file and places them in a binary search tree based on its value. The ID is the first string, the values are the following strings separated by /

Example txt:

```
Abcd/foo/bar//    #ID/value/value2
Abce/foo2//       #ID/value
```

The first line would call:

```
//parser
SequenceMap a;            #has id and value member variables
a.writeAcronym(id);       #Abcd
a.writeValue(value);      #foo
insertNode(a, root);      #Abcd/foo put into tree
a.writeValue(value2);     #bar
insertNode(a, root);      #Abcd/bar put into tree
```

Creating the tree itself doesn't cause the crash, and it works as it should. It's only when I try accessing the minimum value of the tree when it crashes. It still shows the correct minimum value though.

Here's the function that gets the minimum value,
I doubt that this is the root cause of the problem.

But running this in main() crashes my program:

```
    string printMin(Node * x)
    {
        if (x == nullptr)
            return nullptr;       //this isn't ever called, I parse the tree before calling this fucntion
        if (x->left == nullptr)
            return x -> sqmap.getAcronym();  //returns correct value (end of program) then crash
        else
            printMin(x->left);
    }

    void printMain(){
        cout << printMin(root) << endl;
    }
```

main():

```
a.parse("foo.txt");        //doesn't crash
a.printMain();             //crashes when called
                           //but doesn't crash if I remove both a.writeValue(value) from parser
```

Here is the insert/parser:

```
    void parse(string file)         //uses delimiter to split lines
    {
        string line, id, value, value2;
        ifstream myfile(file);

        if (myfile.is_open())
        {
            while(getline(myfile, line))
            {
                if (!line.empty())
                {
                    SequenceMap a;
                    istringstream is(line);
                    getline(is, id, '/');
                    a.writeAcronym(id);
                    getline(is,value, '/');
                    a.writeValue(value);        //program doesn't crash if I remove this

                    insertNode(a, root);

                    getline(is,value2,'/');                

                    if (value2 != "")
                    {
                        a.writeValue(value2);   //program doesn't crash if I remove this
                        insertNode(a, root);
                    }
                }
            }
        myfile.close();
        }
        else
            cout << "Could not open file.";
    }

/*****************************************************/

    void insertNode(SequenceMap & sq, Node * & x)
    {
        if (x == nullptr)
            x = new Node(sq, nullptr, nullptr);
        else if (sq.getValue() < x->sqmap.getValue())
            insertNode(sq, x->left);
        else if (sq.getValue() > x->sqmap.getValue())
            insertNode(sq, x->right);
        else if (sq.getValue() == x->sqmap.getValue())
            x->sqmap.Merge(sq);
    }
```

I'm seriously stuck right now, my only guess is it's a memory bug. Everything works as it should, and I do get the correct minimum value. But right after the last line of code ends, I get the crash. I made a destructor for the tree but that didn't solve it. Can anyone figure this out?

Comment: If `printMin()` returns nullptr you try to `cout` it, why?

Comment: You should compile with warnings switched on, your `printMin` function doesn't always return a value.

Comment: printMin doesn't return a value only if the tree is empty. But I'm not using an empty tree and changing return nullptr to return "" did not work

Comment: You don’t give enough information to tell, but a crash on program exit when everything appears to work can often be a result of a bug where a buffer overrun overwrites a return address on the stack with garbage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`printMin` doesn't return a value when you traverse the left node, so you get a garbage return from that and not a `string`.  If you compile with the warnings all the way up you should get a warning about that.

Comment: printMin does actually return x -> sqmap.getValue();, which is the last line my program runs

Comment: But after the call to `printMin(x->left);` it doesn't.

Comment: Yes it does. In my case, printMin(x->left); is called 7 times THEN return x -> sqmap.getValue(); is called. The value returned is correct, and crashes after

Comment: Which returns back to the printmin, the returned string is destroyed, and the recursive printmin returns garbage.

Comment: 1201 is correct, Seb.   After calling `left->printMin()` (in the `else` clause), the function falls off the end without any return statement.   That causes the caller to exhibit undefined behaviour if it attempts to use the return value.

Comment: I see. I based my code off of http://users.cis.fiu.edu/~weiss/dsaa_c++4/code/BinarySearchTree.h (scroll down to BinaryNode * findMin). Is he wrong too or did I do something different?

Comment: That findmin is always returning a value.  You probably want `return printmin` as the last statement.